# ScalaTest HTML report is malformatted

Tags: scalatest

I can generate the ScalaTest results in HTML but they seem malformatted like in the pic (there's no table to select the test classes)

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JODEq.png)
[image]

I have the following versions of scalatest/pegdown:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test,it",
"org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.0.2" % "test,it"
```

Have anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was setting the scalatest version to `3.0.0` but another version, `3.0.8` was being transitively imported on the project so I added an exclusion rule to this dependency.